Saving via URI scheme: Word not saving to supplied save location?
I'm using the following URI scheme to open a Word file from the browser and save it to my server:
<a href="ms-word:nft|u|https://localhost:5000/static/doc.docx|s|https://localhost:5000/save_doc">Edit Doc</a>

What I expected was that, since I'm pointing |s| to /save_doc, Word would send a PUSH request to /save_doc containing the edited document in some form.
However, it makes an OPTIONS request to /save_doc, receives back that PUSH, PUT and GET are valid methods, and then proceeds to offer saving the document locally with my server's endpoint nowhere in sight as a location.
Is Word expecting something specific in my server's response? Unfortunately, the documentation is pretty sparse on details.
EDIT: Interestingly, a location that does show up is https://localhost:5000/static, which is also being queried by the OPTIONS request. However, I don't want Word to save to there?

FWIW I found this page on GitHub https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/main/docs/embedded/tutorials/launch-experience.md that makes a couple of remarks that may be relevant, but I cannot make sense of them - perhaps you can: 1. "The New From Template may not work as you would expect for save location since the permissions schema is different from SharePoint Sites.", and 2.  The description below that about how to get the correct URL (which presumably also applies to the save location.)
